# Is there an API for localization in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a reactjs app and I'm using [react-table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme) in it. 
The text of the table buttons ("Next", "Page x of y", etc) is in English and I did not see any option to localize it. Is there an API for this? Or should I hook the elements and implement it myself?

Answer (score 5):

In the documentation you can find the list of strings that can be customized, and you can create an object of your custom translations:

```
const translations = {previousText: 'PREV', nextText: 'NEXT', loadingText: 'LOADING...'};
```

Next, just pass this object to your React Table jsx:

```
<ReactTable {...translations} />
```